# Necesito ejemplo básico completo como hacer funcionar el plugin cookie-consent

Tags: html, jquery, cookies

Hola no consigo hacer un ejemplo básico de una página html con un único campo input pero que muestre un aviso al cargarse de aceptación de cookies utilizando el pluging de la pagina https://cookieconsent.insites.com/download.

El amigo Kilo-L me ha enviado en un comentario un link a un código que me funcionado perfectamente cuando accedo desde ese link pero que no me funciona adecuadamente cuando lo copio en un fichero ejemplo.html local a mi ordenador.

Cuando lo lanzo desde mis navegadores Explorer 11 y Chrome (ver.64) ambos sobre win7 el resultado no es el esperado. No muestra la ventana popup y solo se visualiza el campo input.

He comprobado que si accedo directamente desde con mis navegadores a https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cookieconsent2/3.0.3/cookieconsent.min.css y a https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cookieconsent2/3.0.3/cookieconsent.min.js se ve el código que se quiere cargar.

Esta comprobación la hice en Chrome porque al ejecutar el código html el navegador se demora varios segundos antes de visualizar el campo input como si no encontrará lo que intenta cargar. Y de hecho ese parece el problema porque al pulsar F12 obtengo estos errores:

cookieconsent.min.js Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
cookieconsent.min.css Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
ejemplo.html:8 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'initialise' of undefined at ejemploOver.html:8

Este es el código html del fichero ejemplo.html

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cookieconsent2/3.0.3/cookieconsent.min.css" />
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cookieconsent2/3.0.3/cookieconsent.min.js"></script>
<input type="text"/>

<script>
window.addEventListener("load", function(){
window.cookieconsent.initialise({
  "palette": {
    "popup": {
      "background": "#000"
    },
    "button": {
      "background": "#f1d600"
    }
  },
  "position": "top",
  "static": true
})});
</script>
```

¿alguna idea? ¿no entiendo porque no carga las script?

Gracias

Comment: Hola emgodi, bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español. Por favor, lee el recorrido para aprender el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Eso no es todo lo necesario. Para que una pregunta sea de calidad, has de explicar qué intentas hacer y que problemas tienes mostrando tu codigo actual y los errores o fallos que tienes. Pon tambien una explicacion o ejemplos de resultado esperado. Es mejor que pongas el codigo aqui y si es web (html+js) ponerlo en un snippet de codigo para probarlo aqui en vivo. Mira Cómo preguntar y Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable para más info. Un saludo

Comment: ¿Cuál es exactamente el problema? Copiando el código de ejemplo de la web tal cual se muestra el banner. Eso sí, una vez que las aceptas no te vuelve a salir el aviso (salvo que borres las cookies) Aquí te dejo una [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/8h5cbyj8/)

Comment: "no me funciona adecuadamente cuando lo copio en un fichero ejemplo.html local a mi ordenador." ese es el problema, si abres un fichero html en forma local el protocolo es file://  y estás cargando los scripts con // para adaptar a http/https. asi que el navegador intenta cargar desde file://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cookieconsent2/3.0.3/cookieconsent.min.css